# Allow vertical swiping on child elements and horizontal swiping scrolls side-to-side on parent element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, touch, horizontal-scrolling

I have an element that contains a bunch of columns. On a touch device, the columns should be able to scroll up and down using the touch event. When swiping left to right / right to left, I need the parent element / container to horizontally scroll.

The issue I'm running into now is that anytime you try to touch/scroll in one of the columns, it doesn't horizontally scroll the parent element. How can this be accomplished?

I am using the jQuery [Perfect Scrollbar](http://noraesae.github.io/perfect-scrollbar/) plug-in.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/paKkB) (should be tested on a touch device)

HTML

```
<main>
  <section class="red">
    <p>Content...</p>
  </section>
  <section class="green">
    <p>Content...</p>
  </section>
  <section class="blue">
    <p>Content...</p>
  </section>
  <section class="yellow">
    <p>Content...</p>
  </section>
</main>
```

CSS

```
main {
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

section {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: normal;
  height: 300px;
}

p {
  padding: 1em 2em;
  width: 300px;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('section').perfectScrollbar();
```

Answer (score 4):

[This](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Idxvp) seems to work properly on my phone.

```
$('section').perfectScrollbar({
    suppressScrollX: true
});

$('main').perfectScrollbar({
  suppressScrollY: true
});
```

Of course, one could alter the library itself to support the passage of an alternative scrolling element so one doesn't have to use the library twice. That may be a little more time that you're willing to invest, however.

Comment: Very cool. I noticed a bug on my desktop touchscreen if the window has a horizontal scrollbar. The selection can jump about sideways as you touch the child panels. I assume that is a bug in perfectScrollbar?

Comment: That seems the most likely case.